# How to build .ipa file for ios on windows pc using vscode?

Tags: flutter

Good morning all. I am developing a flutter app but i am new to flutter.i am using vscode IDE on windows 8. i can build an apk file for android devices and i want to build .ipa file for iPhone devices on the same PC. My Question is, is there any way to build an .ipa file using vscode on windows.if any solution please share. any help will be appreciated?

Comment: No, a mac OS device is needed to compile an IPA. Closest you get is to set up a CI on another macOS machine (could be a cloud/build server service)

Comment: can share the process to do that?

Comment: If you have a friend/family with a Mac, ask their permission to set up Jenkins on their machine. Otherwise, the Azure Pipeline and Bitrise have free tiers that are enough for small apps/occasional builds. Probably you'd still need an Apple Developer account (99 USD annually) to sign the IPA, so this is an expensive path unless your Android app already made money.

Answer (score 0):

To build iPhone apps (regardless of programming language) you will need a Mac to do it.

That can be your own hardware or you could have a few designated build machines in your company if not everyone can afford a Mac (common scenario) or you can pay a service to do it for you.

But you need a Mac. Sorry.